# Stream Eventhub Fixed Length data to a streaming DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, real-time, azure-eventhub

Summary - I have a streaming source as EventHub where the data is receievd in fixedLength format. Now I want to read the streaming source that contains fixedLength into a spark data frame

Note: I am able to read if the fixedLength is from a directory and create substring and categorize according to my need. But How can I do for streaming source like eventHub (**Since eventhub takes all the data as Body**)

```
Lets take my fixed lenght file is sample.txt that contains - 00101292017you1235
```

My code is like below

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventPosition._
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventHubClientOptions
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.StringUtil
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val endpoint = "Endpoint=sb://XXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXX"
val eventHub = "XXXX"
val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder(endpoint)  .setEventHubName("XXXXX")  .build

val ehConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString).setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)  .setMaxEventsPerTrigger(500)
val ehStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(ehConf.toMap).load
val messages =ehStream.withColumn("Offset", $"offset".cast(LongType)).withColumn("Time (readable)", $"enqueuedTime".cast(TimestampType)).withColumn("Timestamp", $"enqueuedTime".cast(LongType)).withColumn("Body", $"body".cast(StringType)).select("Offset", "Time (readable)", "Timestamp", "Body")
messages.writeStream.outputMode("append").option("truncate", false) .format("console").start() .awaitTermination()
```

For the above scenario how can the body data that recieves in eventhub 00101292017you1235

something like

```
df.select(
    df.value.substr(1,3).alias('id'),
    df.value.substr(4,8).alias('date'),
    df.value.substr(12,3).alias('string'),
    df.value.substr(15,4).cast('integer').alias('integer')
).show
will result in:

+---+--------+------+-------+
| id|    date|string|integer|
+---+--------+------+-------+
|001|01292017|   you|   1234|
|002|01302017|    me|   5678|
+---+--------+------+-------+
```

Comment: This Helps 
val messages =ehStream.withColumn("FirstColumn", $"body".substr(1,3).cast(StringType)).select("FirstColumn")

Anyother suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This Helps

```
val messages =ehStream.withColumn("FirstColumn",$"body".substr(1,3).cast(StringType)).select("FirstColumn")
```